# Displaying a ListView at the bottom of an activity

Tags: android, listview

I'm new to developing on Android, so bear with me. I have an activity that displays some weather data for today's date, and I want to have a list of more weather data at the bottom of the activity for the next 7 days, like this:

[image]

However, I'm confused about what the best way to achieve this is. I was thinking of using a ListView but I'm confused about how to use them. From what I've gathered, I need to create a ListView layout in `res/layout` and then use a fragment on my main activity, which has its layout set to the ListView layout I just made. Is that correct? Or would an easier solution be to just have a ListView placed at the bottom of my main activity?

Or, am I using the completely wrong control for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this layout very easily by this code:

```
<Relativelayout...>

    <EditText android="@+id/edit1"
      android:alignParentTop="true"
      ... />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/YOUR_MIDDLE_DATA"
      android:above="@+id/listview1"
      android:below="@+id/edit1" ...>
      ...
      ...
    </Linearlayout>

    <Listview android:id="@+id/listview1"
      android:above="@+id/txt1"
      ... />

    <Textview android:id="@+id/txt1"
      ...
      android:alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use weight also for your customization.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the XML that follows as an example. In this (an actual XML from an app of mine), I have a smaller `EditText` above the `ListView`, but you can change it to something else that you would need. What this essentially illustrates is that you can have a `ListView` along with some other content at the top or at the bottom. (I have the Admob code after the `ListView` which I have removed)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_thing_comment_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editFilterList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/phone_thing_comment_box"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/filter_search_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Type Friends Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textColorHint="#ff78797d"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:divider="#000000"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/no_friends"
            android:textColor="#f1f1f1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The *pros* of using this method is that the `ListView` will scroll like it should but the `Widgets` above it will always be stationary. The *cons* of using this method is that on devices with smaller screens, *there might not be enough room* for the `ListView` contents to show and the user might have to scroll a lot.

Alternatively, you can separate the `Widgets` above the `ListView`, put them in a different XML file and add it to your `ListView` (in the Java code) as a `Header`. This makes the content above the `ListView` move along with the `ListView` contents.

So this piece of code goes in a different XML that will be added as a Header in your Java code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_thing_comment_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editFilterList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/phone_thing_comment_box"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/filter_search_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="Type Friends Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#ff333333"
            android:textColorHint="#ff78797d"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The pros and cons are pretty much the opposite of the earlier example.

Either of the methods will work regardless of being used in a `Fragment` or an `Activity`.